# What does negative character offset in chrome's stacktrace mean?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I track exceptions on website and sometimes I get stacktraces from Chrome users with negative character offset like

```
at http://my.website.com/some/path:415:-193
```

This only happens for errors in inline scripts (and never in separate files). Does anybody knows what this means?

Comment: How does the inline script look like? Can you reduce it to a minimum case?